# Looping over a range of numbers in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm quite new to Data Factory and have a question regarding looping over a list of consecutive numbers.

I have been assigned a task to retrieve data from an api in Data Factory (based on a pre-existing template). The problem is that the api is split into multiple pages and the link is :".../2020/entries?skippages=**1**&pagesize=1000".

In my pipeline I therefore need to loop over the page number (the number of iterations is 11).
I have looked a bit into ForEach and Until loops but it seems a lot more complicated than need be.

What is best practice for such a task?

Hopefully, this makes sense. If not, please let me know and I will elaborate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue? I am having some difficulty finding the solution, and I was curious whether your issue is similar to mine. This is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186437/pagination-rules-value-in-azure-data-factory-v2-for-rest-api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Synapse Pipelines have a [number of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) you can use in your pipelines, including `range` which generates a range of numbers.

All you have to do is specify `range` in the `Items` section of a ForEach loop.  A simple example:

[image: ADF range example]

To explain the definition a bit further, all ADF expressions (not including Mapping Data Flows) start with the `@` symbol, `range` is the function, 1 is the start index and 11 is the count or max number to reach.  See the help for the `range` function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#range).

In order to access the number inside the loop, use the `item()` syntax, remember `@` at the start of the expression.

As you are paging from a web API, you should have a good look at the [Pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support) section of the Copy activity which may offer an alternate and more dynamic approach depending on the capabilities of the API you are calling.